# Over come Foreign Key Constraint by limiting SELECT data

Tags: sql-server, primary-key

I'm copying data from SOURCE to DEST.

Both are identically structured databases for use by the same software.

The table I'm currently working with has PK on ITEM_CODE and VEND_CODE

The source has various vendor codes including 100004

The destination needs to have 100004 set as the VEND code all the way down.

My plan was only to bring across the rows from SOURCE with the VEND_CODE set to 100004

I've written the following which is failing thus:

```
INSERT DEST.dbo.ITEM_REPLENISH_VENDOR(
[ITEM_CODE],[VEND_CODE],[PRIMARY_VENDOR],[PURCHASE_MEASURE],
[STD_COST],[LAST_COST],[EOQ],[VENDOR_PART_NO],[LEAD_TIME],[COST])
SELECT s.[ITEM_CODE],s.[VEND_CODE],'T','EA','0','0','0','0','0', '0' 
FROM SOURCE.dbo.ITEM_REPLENISH_VENDOR s 
LEFT OUTER JOIN DEST.dbo.ITEM_REPLENISH_VENDOR d
ON (d.ITEM_CODE = s.ITEM_CODE) -- AND (d.VEND_CODE = s.VEND_CODE)
WHERE d.ITEM_CODE IS NULL AND s.[VEND_CODE] = '100004'
```

ERROR:

```
Msg 547, Level 16, State 0, Line 2 
The INSERT statement conflicted with the FOREIGN KEY constraint "FK_ITEM_REPLENISH_VENDOR_ITEMS". 
The conflict occurred in database "DEST", table "dbo.ITEMS", column 'ITEMNO'.
The statement has been terminated.'
```

I assume my syntax is wrong for how I've done the script.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As there is foreign key constraint in table **ITEM_REPLENISH_VENDOR** referencing item code in **items** table

You need to first insert missing  item codes in destination table **items**

Your current query is good

Comment: Geez is it that simple!?!?!?!?!? TY!  I will report back.

Comment: That was all it needed.